# Problems with Contextual Filters & Menu Tabs

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes, views

I have created a collection of views (base) that collects identifies a category of articles and a second single view (tabs) that creates tabs to filter the content into sub categories for all base views using contextual filters.

- I have created two vocabularies to contain terms for Section and part.
- A sample base uses the path /division/SectionTerm.
- The path for the tabs view is /division/%1/part.
- Each page of the tabs view has a filter to a specific part term.

The idea is to have a series of menu tabs that display different related content related to a section.  This works fine in a test without the contextual filter, but the tabs do not show when I change to contextual filters for the tabs view although the preview is showing correct results.

I am having a similar problem having a view block using relations appear.  See separate question post.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar, I think, but it is driven by Taxonomy Menu.  For what it is worth (for any other researchers), I have set a contextual filter and a relationship:

[image]

Contextual filter settings:

[image: screenshot1 view contextual filters]
[image: screenshot2 view contextual filters]
[image: screenshot3 view contextual filters]

And my relationship (see 1st screenshot) setting is just default:

[image: screenshot view relationship]